# Recognize date in libre calc

Tags: libreoffice

I imported a column with dates in my sheet. The are of the form yyyymmdd. Thus 20121023, 20121022 etc .

I want to apply date related functions on this column, but for libre office these fields are just numbers. How can I make libre office recognize them as dates?

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the range of cells that contains the imported dates.

   [image]
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to launch the Format Cells dialog box.

   In the **Format Cells** dialog box, do the following:

   - Select the **Date** category.
   - Select a valid date **Format**.

     - You can also create a custom (user-defined) date format by typing a format on the **Format code** text field and clicking on **Add** (the check mark) button.
   - Click the **OK** button.

   [image]

**Note**: Another way of launching the Format Cells dialog box is by right-clicking on the selected range and selecting **Format Cells...** from the context menu.

**You can now perform date calculations on the selected range.**

Answer (score 0):

Select the column number (eg A) of the spreadsheet that contains the dates. Right-click and select 'Format Cells'. Select 'DATE' category from the left-hand panel. Choose your desired format and apply the changes.

You can easily use date-functions on the column(s) now.